# Django: "Object has not attribute get" error in forms.Form

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to create a `forms.Form` that loads an existing `Trade` record and allows users to update it. I believe the usual way to do this would be to use a `forms.ModelForm`, but ModelForms do not work with the widget I am using (django-autocomplete).

When I load the url `/update-buy/263/`, it calls the `views.update_buy` function (shown below). I am getting the error `'ManyToOneRel' object has no attribute 'attname'.`

**Form:**

```
class BuyUpdateForm(LoginRequiredMixin, forms.Form):
    desired_game = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Game.objects.all(),
        to_field_name='desired_game', #todo
        widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(
            url='game-autocomplete',
            attrs={
                'data-minimum-input-length': 2,
            },
        )
    )

    buy_price = forms.IntegerField()

    def __init__(self, data, *args, **kwargs): 
        super(BuyUpdateForm, self).__init__(data, *args, **kwargs)
        if data is not None:
            self.fields['buy_price'].label = "Max. Buy Price"
            self.fields['buy_price'].initial = data['buy_price']
            self.fields['desired_game'].initial = data['desired_game']
```

**views.update_buy**(method called when user loads the above url)

```
@login_required
def update_buy(request, pk):
    offer = Trade.objects.filter(id=pk).first()
    print('offer: ' + str(offer))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        trade_form = BuyUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=offer)
        if trade_form.is_valid():
            trade_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your trade has been updated')
            return redirect('update-offer/' + str(pk))

    else: #GET request
        data = {'desired_game': offer.desired_game, 'buy_price': offer.buy_price}
        trade_form = BuyUpdateForm(data)
        return render(request, 'blog/buy_form.html', {'form': trade_form, 'title': 'Update Trade Form'} )
```

**relevant fields from the Trade model:**

```
class Trade(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField() # Unrestricted text
    desired_game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='desired_game', db_column='desired_game', null=True, blank=True)
    buy_price = models.IntegerField(default=None, null=True, blank=True)


    def get_trade_name(self):
        return ''.join([self.user_who_posted.username, '(', timezone.now().strftime("%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S UTC"), ')'])

    def get_condition_choices(self):
        return self.CONDITION_CHOICES

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name = self.get_trade_name()
        super(Trade, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name # return game name when game.objects.all() is called
```

**UPDATE: This is what the form looks like when I use ModelForm**. This results in the error `'ManyToOneRel' object has no attribute 'attname'`

```
class BuyUpdateForm(LoginRequiredMixin, forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Trade
        fields = ['desired_game', 'buy_price']

    desired_game = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Game.objects.all(),
        to_field_name='desired_game', #todo
        widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(
            url='game-autocomplete',
            attrs={
                'data-minimum-input-length': 2,
            },
        )
    )
```

Comment: Only ModelForms have a save() method. I don't why can't use ModelForm instead of a normal Form.

Comment: @EPaul when i use a ModelForm, it works if i have the desired_game field as a regular ModelChoiceField, but I get this error when i add the django-autocomplete widget: `'ManyToOneRel' object has no attribute 'attname'
`

Comment: Can you show us the game-autocomplete view?

Comment: I updated the answer to add the ModelForm version. Also, here is the documentation on creating an autocomplete view: https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#create-an-autocomplete-view

Comment: Try removing the to_field_name field in your form. That changes the option's value and It will mess up your select if you replace the id of the object with another id.

Comment: OMG, you are exactly correct, that fixed it immediately! thanks really appreciate it!